# Is it feasible to use a gaming mouse for software development?

Tags: mouse, macros

I was just thinking, after seeing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/523220/awesome-visual-studio-macros) over at stackoverflow, if it would be possible to assign such macros to the macro keys of gaming mouses. I'm not entirely sure how much sense that makes yet, hence this question.
It is possible, of course, to assign these macros to a shortcut on the keyboard, but I don't see a clear advantage in doing that. 
So basically I don't see why you shouldn't use a mouse's macro keys for software development. Yet I find absolutely nothing about the use of these mouses in software development. Why is that?

Comment: Because your hands shouldn't be leaving the keyboard.

Comment: So, you're telling me, superusers strive to not use their mouse?

Comment: @bumbumfish yes, it's exactly that. A beginner  "mouser" is faster than a beginner "keyboarder" but a seasonned "keyboarder" is faster than a seasonned "mouser"

Comment: @JoBedard Are there reliable sources for this or is this a religious war, as described [here](http://www.asktog.com/TOI/toi06KeyboardVMouse1.html). That link also indicates that the opposite is true. At least for editing, that makes sense to me.

Comment: @bumbumfish I at least go to great lengths not to leave the keyboard.  It even *annoys me* when applications (*coughvspherecough*) do not offer methods of navigation through the keyboard.

Comment: Good article : http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/02/keyboarding.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Feasible? Yes.
Practical? *Absolutely not.*

Software development is in the business of generating content (a *lot* of content) and the mouse simply doesn't lend itself to this purpose as an HCI device.  Mice are used today primarily to *consume* content.

Look at your keyboard.  Now look at your mouse.  Back to your keyboard.  Back to your mouse. Your mouse doesn't have keys, but your keyboard does.  Your mouse wishes it did, but (back to being serious) *if* your mouse had the keys a keyboard did, it would cause undue strain to the joints of your fingers which are so crucial.  It's not healthy to cram that much mechanical functionality into such a small device.

---

'Super users', if we call them/ourselves that, would like nothing better than a completely keyboard-driven working environment unless, of course, our work is of a graphical nature.  (I wouldn't necessarily want to be moving around class diagrams with my keyboard.)  We spend so much time on the keyboard *creating content* and we become such *excellent* typists that it *frustrates us* to take the time to reach for the mouse, perform some menial task with it, and move back to the keyboard to get the *real* work done.

Comment: Absolutely. GUIs can be frustrating at times when you're used to being very efficient with your keyboard.

Comment: I agree! And looking at habits the only consumption I really do is web, and with that its mostly mouse (Although I do F4 or F5 for address bar which is one of the two depending on browser). Other than that its F keys, <kbd>Win</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, del, insert, end, home, page, arrows, 10-key etc. ***nothing*** is worse than having to reach to the mouse for one or two clicks.